# Dataset of Hard Instances of SUBSET-SUM

Tags: subset-sum

I know for factoring we have the RSA Numbers, in which factoring one of them quickly (usually) indicates a breakthrough in the field. However, I want to know if there's something similar for SUBSET-SUM, in which there are hard instances that if solved, would be a "big deal"? I found [this](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/datasets/subset_sum/subset_sum.html), but they don't seem to be unsolved.

One way would to take the RSA numbers, convert them to 3-SAT, then convert to SUBSET-SUM, but the weights generated are very large. Maybe there's a way to convert FACTOR (the special case of two prime factors, to be specific) directly to SUBSET-SUM without having to go through 3SAT (not the main question; just a thought)?

For the RSA numbers in particular, we know how long each non-trivial factor is: $\frac k2$, where $k$ is the number of bits of the number $n$. Maybe we can use that to shrink the number of variables to only $n$, without having to make extra variables and unnecessarily fill the problem with "junk".

Comment: How large is "very large"? They sorta have to be large to form a hard instance.

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz For example, in one similar question (can't find it), for two variables and three clauses, one of the weights was $11223$.

Comment: Don't expect "short" weights because SUBSET-SUM is weakly NPC and you have a pseudo-polynomial algorithm for it. The conversion from 3SAT is straightforward so you could also use hard 3SAT instances from datasets used in Sat competitions or use a constraint satisfaction program as a "preprocessor" to quickly generate SAT instances from FACTOR and then convert them to SUBSET SUM

Comment: @Vor Since the conversion from SAT to 3SAT usually makes the problem harder, I wonder if I could just convert FACTOR to SAT, then to SUBSET-SUM. While it won't give me "short" weights, it would almost certainly give me an easier problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I'm having a hard time telling what exactly the question is.  I tried answering, but got the feedback that I wasn't answering the main question.  It would also help to ask only one question, so there is no risk of confusion about what you are asking.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for still caring about this question! My question was basically, is there some SUBSET-SUM instance that is known to be *extremely* hard, such that solving them (in a reasonable time) would indicate that a proposed algorithm for SUBSET-SUM has a higher chance to be truly polynomial time?

Answer (score 0):

Note that FACTOR isn't known to be NP-complete.

Comment: But can't you not still convert it into a 3-SAT instance?